# getElementById.value is not working ERROR: form1.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: f1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (form1.html:10)

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I've been trying a lot to run this code, but unfortunately it didn't seem to work; It says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `value` of `null`

I noticed that `getElementById().value` is the culprit but it prints results without error when I run another file on the same `browser(CHROME, IE, FIREFOX)` which was pre executed on another computer already.

And also `getElementById` used to work perfectly a few months ago.

Please help me. This is frustrating! Thanks in advance

```js
function f1()
{
 document.write("Hello")

 var cname = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
 document.write(cname);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 
 Enter Name: <input id="user_name" type="text"  /><br/>
 <button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="form1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you not notice the entire document disappear when you click the button? You replaced the entire DOM with a single text node, so there's no longer a `user_name` to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After printing hello your page DOM is reloaded where textfield is not present that's why it's not working try below one code

```
function f1()
{
    var cname = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    document.write("Hello "+cname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very so much Jay! You explained very well where I went wrong. I was literally frustrated. You guys just rescued me. You guys are champions.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

> `document.write` overides all content in the body and is also conceptually terrible performance-wise. As for wrapping `"Hello"` and the variable `cname` in `document.createTextNode`, I do so to convert the primitive string type to an actual DOM string. And finally, this *DOM string* is appended to the body element.

The cool thing about this is that you get to choose which element you wanna append the content to.

Try this:

```js
 function f1() {
   document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello "));

   var cname = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
  
   document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cname));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 
 Enter Name: <input id="user_name" type="text"  /><br/>
 <button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="form1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Thank you so much @bukharim96 . This is a big relief for me. This is printing results as expected but ca you please explain this code and why my code wasn't working; If possible....

Comment: My pleasure. `;D`

Answer (score 1):

This code `document.write("Hello")` is replacing your entire HTML, therefore the input element with id `user_name` is being lost.

## `Document.write()`

> `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.

You can either remove that line of code `document.write("Hello")` or follow this example:

```js
function f1() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"));

  var cname = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\n' + cname));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>

</head>

<body>
  Enter Name: <input id="user_name" type="text" /><br/>
  <button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very so much Ele! You explained very well where I went wrong. I was literally frustrated. You guys just rescued me. You guys are champions.